# SineCosine Wave

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, numpy

As a beginner this is my first code. Any comments?

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

x=np.linspace(-360,360,45)*np.pi/180
plt.subplot(111)
_sin=plt.plot(x, np.sin(x),label="Sine Curve")
_cos=plt.plot(x,np.cos(x),label="Cos Curve")
#_tan=plt.plot(x,np.tan(x),label="Tan Curve")
plt.legend(['sin','cos','tan'])

plt.show()#This line might be required on some python implementations.
```

Comment: (To split an excessively fine hair, not specifying in any way what the code is to accomplish (beyond naming a theme) makes it correspondingly hard to tell whether the code works as intended.)

Comment: @greybeard Considering the title, I think it's supposed to plot (co)sine waves.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [SuperStormer's points](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/253238/100620) ...

## Unused variables

`_sin` and `_cos` are never used.  You don't need to assignments to these variable.

## Naming conventions

In the event you will eventually use them...

Leading underscore are used to indicate private members of a class.  To avoid collisions with keywords, by convention, a trailing underscore is used (i.e. `sin_` & `cos_`).

## Unused arguments

`'tan'` is being passed to `plt.legend()`, but there is no tangent plot.

It works, but it is a bad habit to get into. Pass the desired curve titles directly to the `plt.plot()` function (i.e.`, label="sin"`), and simply call `plt.legend()` with no arguments.

## Magic numbers

What is `111` and why are you passing it to `subplot()`?

## Updated code

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

x = np.linspace(-360, 360, 45) * np.pi / 180

plt.subplot()
sin_ = plt.plot(x, np.sin(x), label="sin")
cos_ = plt.plot(x, np.cos(x), label="cos")
#tan_ = plt.plot(x, np.tan(x), label="tan")

plt.legend()

# plt.show()   # For CPython
```

Answer (score 2):

First, [use pyplot instead of pylab.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469336/what-is-the-difference-between-pylab-and-pyplot)

Secondly, check out [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the Python style guide. stdlib imports should be at the very top, then 3rd-party imports. However, `math` isn't even used anywhere, so you can just remove the import entirely.

In addition, your spacing is a bit inconsistent. Assignments should have 1 space on each side and there should be a space after the commas within a func call. I recommend using an auto-formatter to fix these stylistic issues, such as black or yapf.